# If $a^k$=e where k is odd, then the order of a is odd

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let a,b, and c be elements of a group G. Prove the following:
>
> If $a^k$=e where k is odd, then the order of $a$ is odd

Here is how I worked on the proof:

Assume $a^k$=e where k is odd. Since k is odd then k=2L+1 for L $\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore, through replacement:

$a^k$=$a^{2L+1}$=$a^{2L} \times a$=e

I'm really tempted to say since L is any integer, $a^{2L}$ will always be even while a is odd and the result will be odd but i'm thinking in terms of permutations. The problem I'm having is I'm not sure how to connect it, well...that is if I am on the right track in the first place.

Comment: Not the right track. You may already have seen the theorem that if $a^k=e$ then the order of $a$ divides $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of $a$ is $m$ and $a^k=e$, then consider the quotient $q$ and remainder $r$ when dividing $k$ by $m$ so $k=mq+r$ with $0 \le r \lt m$.

You then have $e=a^{mq+r}=a^{mq} \,a^r=(a^m)^q \,a^r = e^q\, a^r = a^r$, and since $r \lt m$ you must have $r=0$ as otherwise the order of $a$ would be $r$ rather than $m$.

If $r=0$ than $k$ is a multiple of $m$, so $k$ being odd implies $m$ must be odd since all multiples of even numbers are even.

Answer (score 3):

Let $o(a)=m$

then $m$ divides $k$ ;
since $k$ is odd $m$ must be odd

Comment: why down vote for this answer?

Comment: I did not downvote. I just worked on this exercise on my own. Does this reasoning make sense: 

Since $n$ must be non-zero, the first legal $n$ value is $1$. 
Because $a^{k}=e$ when $k$ is odd, and $1$ is odd, then $a$'s 
order must be $1$, i.e. odd.